# displaytag url no param value

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I am using display tag to create a table. One column has a url with a parameter name and value appended.

```
<display:column value="response" url="/response.html" paramId="respID" paramProperty="respID"
style="text-align:center; " title="Response" sortable="false">
</display:column>
```

The problem i am having is even though i create all the links , there are certain links for which there is no paramete value of respID. The corresponding url of those column is

```
http://testlocalhost:7001/whpet/response.html?respID=
```

(notice there is nothing after equal )

In normal case the url is formed as

```
http://testlocalhost:7001/whpet/response.html?respID=response-681
```

What can i do so that nothing appears when there is no value of the param respID

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the url?

You can use c:if jstl library to check if there is no value and only then create the url.

```
<c:if test="${not empty variableName}">
    variableName is not empty or null.
</c:if>
```

Comment: It was not visible when I answered. Seems display:column tag does not have any way. I would set the value for that column with using the url feature of display:column. You can use the c:if and other logic to create url inside display:tag body/